AB Test on Journey Builder
In Content Builder there is a feature called as AB Testing now I created an Email for that AB test and gave a name.If I place that Email in Journey Builder  the Subscribers only receiving the ABTest 1 Email (1st Email)and not the second one I want both mails to reach my subscribers randomly. How could I possibly achieve this in Journey Builder.
Note: I already have that existing Email in the Journey Builder now the requirement is in that existing Email when I Insert AB Test Block it should reach to my subscribers randomly.

Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/281289/83900
